# Explicitly using service account credentials in code for speech recognition

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

Let it be stated that this is the first time I'm working with Google Cloud, so this is probably a noob question.

I want to use the Google Cloud Speech library to do some speech to text on an audio file. I also want to explicitly state within the code which Google Cloud service account credentials to use by giving the private key file. How do I do so?

It seems that what I want is a mix of [this quickstart for speech recognition](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/quickstart.py) and [this example of how to set credentials within the code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/auth/cloud-client/snippets.py) (the `explicit()` part).

I tried doing so, but `explicit()` uses `google.cloud.storage` to set the client,

```
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json')
```

in order to make the API request.

Setting

```
client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('service_account.json')
```

and then running

```
client.recognize(config, audio)
```

obviously throws an error saying that `client` doesn't have that attribute. My guess is what I need is something similar, but for `google.cloud.speech`? I have tried looking through the documentation - am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost all of the Google Client libraries follow the same design pattern for credentials. In the example below, the code loads the credentials and then creates the client using those credentials.

[Link to the Speech Client](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/speech/gapic/v1p1beta1/api.html)

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from google.cloud import speech_v1
from google.cloud.speech_v1 import enums

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'service-account.json'

cred = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

client = speech_v1.SpeechClient(credentials=cred)
```

OR (Notice not specifying scopes which is usually OK)

```
client = speech_v1.SpeechClient.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
```